# Easiest way to deploy macros for Word to users?

Tags: vba, templates, deployment, ms-word

I used this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/deploy-your-word-macros-from-a-central-location-HA001087294.aspx and set everything up on a shared drive.  However, I am having a small issue.

The issue is that when I run any of the macros I get a popup box that says "Code execution has been interupted" and I can click continue/end or help (debug is grey'd out).  If I just keep clicking continue the macro will run properly but I just keep getting that popup throughout the macro run.

When these macros are in the Normal.dot global template file I do not have these issues.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use our Active Directory start up scripts to push our macros to users at my workplace. In the users "application data" within the Microsoft/office folders you will find a "startup" folder.

Any .dot or .doc files in this directory will have their macros loaded when word runs (including any custom toolbars).

There is also a copy of the folder at the machine level (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\STARTUP on my laptop) that will do the same for all users of a machine.

If AD start up scripts are not an option perhaps use boot scripts (or .bat file sin the users Program Files/Startup directory) to copy from a network location on login.

Comment: I just re-read your question. Hopefully using the dir's that I mentioned will get past the "code execution" bug. Its a issue with whether the code is trusted. You might also want to look at the security setting under macros in word (again can be set within AD).